# self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios7.1

I am developing a simple ios app in swift that gets the location of the user and shows the location. I need to set this app to target ios 7.0 and higher so iPhone 4 users can use this app. However, when i set the 
`Deployment Target` to `7.0` I get a build error saying:

> /Users/toing_toing/dev/xyz/HomePageViewController.swift:35:30:
>   'requestAlwaysAuthorization()' is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer

It comes from this line:

```
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

I need the app to access GPS all the time for the moment, but I cant find a replacement code for this that will fix the deployment target error. What can I do?

Comment: Before iOS 8, starting updates on the locationManager did generate a request to the user if no consent is given. Also, there was no differentiation between different types of location permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`

```
var authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
if (authorizationStatus == .AuthorizedWhenInUse || authorizationStatus == .AuthorizedAlways {
  locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}else if self.locationManager.respondsToSelector(Selector("requestAlwaysAuthorization")) {
   self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}else {
   locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: Actually, on iOS 8+, you should not start updating before successful authorization. So, wrap that `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` in an `else`.

Comment: I used `if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        } else {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }`
and it solved the issue, apparently this is the suggested fix for this issue in xcode, but i didnt notice it!
Your answer still gives the error. But thanks a lot for helping :)

Comment: Quick tip, always use availability check, not os version check, if they remove that thing in future your code still works.